# ExtJS Close button on each tab in a Tabpanel

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

The Extjs API site adds a new tab for each search you do.

The tabs each have a red X on them to close the tab similar to what browsers have.

Check it out here:

I'd like to replicate this and it seems like something that would be built-in to the API, but cannot find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer. You pass in:  {closable: true} with the config object.